# How to escape trial go-around with system time change?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, registry

Hi have an application offering a 30 days trial. When installed, I am adding a registry key with the current `DateTime.Now` value.

```
installDate = DateTime.Now;
RegistryKey regKeyAppRoot = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(registryKeyPath); 
regKeyAppRoot.SetValue("InstallDate", installDate);
```

Whenever the application is started, I load the value from the registry and compare it to the current `DateTime.Now` value again and obviously depending on the result of the comparison I show appropriate messages.

```
RegistryKey regKeyAppRoot = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(registryKeyPath); 
installDate = (DateTime)regKeyAppRoot.GetValue("InstallDate");
if (installDate.AddDays(30) > DateTime.Now)
    ; //MessageBox.Show(...)
```

My problem is that a simple change of the system time (to the past) would just allow the usage of the application again as the condition will no longer be met. That is explicable as the [DateTime.Now property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx) gets a DateTime object that is set to the current date and time **on this computer**, expressed as the local time.

How can I escape that and get the exact number of days since when my application was installed?

Comment: And how about a user who knows how to edit the registry?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: that will be the location and the name of the key. I used clean names here to show the example, but have a look at the kind of keys Microsoft uses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save the date of the last check and compare the current date. If they are on different days, then increment a counter. In this way the user has "at most" 30 day uses.

So...

```
DateTime lastCheck = ... // Recover it from the registry

DateTime now = DateTime.Now.Date;

if (now != lastCheck.Date)
{
    UsesCounter++;
}

lastCheck = now;
```

I'll add that normally it's a little better to use `UtcNow`, not `Now`, in this way you are safe from Daylight Time changes.

Another option is to use an Internet clock :-) There are many sites that give the exact time (this option is good only if your program normally connect to Internet)

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach would be to save the date and time each time the program is started and quit. The next start compares the current date and time to the saved one. If it is less than the saved one, your application refuses to start.
This certainly wouldn't completely remove that problem, but it would make it harder for the user, because he would need to know what date and time he needs to set his computer to.

Answer (score 0):

If you save time, when your application ended, you can check that current time is greater than ended time